# How to create user defined python REST service in bluemix

Tags: python, rest, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create my own python RESTFUL service in ibm-bluemix.  Is there a template or documentation for doing this somewhere?

Comment: Do you already have something that works outside of Bluemix, or are you still figuring out how to do it at all?

Comment: I have a program that accepts a json input and creates a json output that I want to turn into a REST service on bluemix.  Most of the examples I can find use flask and are creating an app rather than a service.  I don't need a user interface.  I just want it to be a service like the watson services for example that have a url and a username/password and are called with a REST interface.